# Adding hidden spaces between buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a single scrolling webpage consisting of three pages

```js
$('a.page-scroll').on('click', function(event) {
  var $anchor = $(this);
  $('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 60
  }, 1000);
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
* {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
#page1 {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
}
#page2 {
  height: 1000px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #18121e;
  padding-top: 140px;
  border-top: 100px;
}
#page3 {
  height: 650px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #233237;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-top: 200px;
}
body {
  padding-top: 0px;
}
#page1 p {
  padding-top: 100px;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}
#page1 p #highlight {
  color: pink !important;
}
#page2 h3 {
  padding-bottom: 80px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
#page3 h3 {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.btn {
  color: white;
  background-color: #000 !important;
}
.btn:hover {
  color: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.nicescroll/3.6.7/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Rashid Naushad</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<!--<div class="container-fluid">-->
<div>
  <div id="page1">
    <a id="about"></a>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p class="text-center">Hi !
      <br>I'm a self taught web developer based in India.
      <br>I'm an undergraduate student pursuing economics who just loves to <span id="highlight">code</span>.
      <br>I dream of combining my knowledge of programming, economics, and
      <br>financial markets for the betterment of the society.
      <br>Languages and Frameworks:
      <br>HTML5, CSS3, Bootstrap3,
      <br>Javascript, jQuery, Angular.js, Meteor.js,
      <br>Node.js, React,js,
      <br>Python, php..
      <br>Tools & expertise: Git, Responsive Web Design.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="page2">
    <a id="portfolio"></a>
    <h3 class="text-center">Here is my latest portfolio, <br>I'll be adding more as I learn and grow..</h3>
    <!--<div class="row">
      <div class="thumbnail img img-responsive">
        <p data-height="268" data-theme-id="0" data-slug-hash="VaKMBJ" data-default-tab="result" data-user="rashidnaushad" data-preview="true" class="codepen">See the Pen <a href="http://codepen.io/rashidnaushad/pen/VaKMBJ/">Simple Javascript App</a> by Rashid Naushad (<a href="http://codepen.io/rashidnaushad">@rashidnaushad</a>) on <a href="http://codepen.io">CodePen</a>.</p>
        <script async src="//assets.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js"></script>
      </div>

      <div class="thumbnail img img-responsive">
        <p data-height="268" data-theme-id="0" data-slug-hash="pyPjae" data-default-tab="result" data-user="rashidnaushad" data-preview="true" class="codepen">See the Pen <a href="http://codepen.io/rashidnaushad/pen/pyPjae/">Tribute to Raghuram Rajan</a> by Rashid Naushad (<a href="http://codepen.io/rashidnaushad">@rashidnaushad</a>) on <a href="http://codepen.io">CodePen</a>.</p>
        <script async src="//assets.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js"></script>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="img img-responsive img-rounded" src="http://cleantallahassee.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/coming-soon.jpg" alt="Coming Soon!" />
        <div class="caption">
          <h5 class="text-center">Coming Soon!</h5>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="img img-responsive img-rounded" src="http://cleantallahassee.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/coming-soon.jpg" alt="Coming Soon!" />
        <div class="caption">
          <h5 class="text-center">Coming Soon!</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>-->
  </div>

  <div id="page3">
    <a id="contact"></a>
    <h3 id="contact-text" class="text-center">Think I can be of any help to you?<br>Wanna collaborate?<br>Shoot me a message, now!</h3>
    <a href="https://github.com/rashidnaushad" class="btn btn-lg col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2" target="_blank">GitHub</a>
    <div class="hidden-lg hidden-md">
      <br>
    </div>
    <a href="https://www.freecodecamp.com/rashidnaushad" class="btn btn-lg col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2" target="_blank">freeCodeCamp</a>
    <div class="hidden-lg hidden-md">
      <br>
    </div>
    <a href="mailto:rashidnaushad3@gmail.com" class="btn btn-lg col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2" target="_blank">Gmail</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The buttons on the third page,when collapsed don't leave a space in between. How do I add space between the buttons in the `sm`all and `xs`mall screen sizes?I tried inserting 
 between the buttons, but that didn't work.
Here is the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rashidnaushad/pc0u790m/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your CSS

```
@media screen and (max-width: 990px) {

  .btn ~ .btn {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/pc0u790m/8/)

Sample snippet

```js
$('a.page-scroll').on('click', function(event) {
  var $anchor = $(this);
  $('html, body').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top - 60
  }, 1000);
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
* {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
#page1 {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
}
#page2 {
  height: 1000px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #18121e;
  padding-top: 140px;
  border-top: 100px;
}
#page3 {
  height: 650px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #233237;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-top: 200px;
}
body {
  padding-top: 0px;
}
#page1 p {
  padding-top: 100px;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}
#page1 p #highlight {
  color: pink !important;
}
#page2 h3 {
  padding-bottom: 80px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
#page3 h3 {
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
.btn {
  color: white;
  background-color: #000 !important;
}
.btn:hover {
  color: gray;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 990px) {

  .btn ~ .btn {
    margin-top: 10px;
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.nicescroll/3.6.7/jquery.nicescroll.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Rashid Naushad</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<!--<div class="container-fluid">-->
<div>
  <div id="page1">
    <a id="about"></a>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p class="text-center">Hi !
      <br>I'm a self taught web developer based in India.
      <br>I'm an undergraduate student pursuing economics who just loves to <span id="highlight">code</span>.
      <br>I dream of combining my knowledge of programming, economics, and
      <br>financial markets for the betterment of the society.
      <br>Languages and Frameworks:
      <br>HTML5, CSS3, Bootstrap3,
      <br>Javascript, jQuery, Angular.js, Meteor.js,
      <br>Node.js, React,js,
      <br>Python, php..
      <br>Tools & expertise: Git, Responsive Web Design.</p>
  </div>

  <div id="page2">
    <a id="portfolio"></a>
    <h3 class="text-center">Here is my latest portfolio, <br>I'll be adding more as I learn and grow..</h3>
    <!--<div class="row">
      <div class="thumbnail img img-responsive">
        <p data-height="268" data-theme-id="0" data-slug-hash="VaKMBJ" data-default-tab="result" data-user="rashidnaushad" data-preview="true" class="codepen">See the Pen <a href="http://codepen.io/rashidnaushad/pen/VaKMBJ/">Simple Javascript App</a> by Rashid Naushad (<a href="http://codepen.io/rashidnaushad">@rashidnaushad</a>) on <a href="http://codepen.io">CodePen</a>.</p>
        <script async src="//assets.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js"></script>
      </div>

      <div class="thumbnail img img-responsive">
        <p data-height="268" data-theme-id="0" data-slug-hash="pyPjae" data-default-tab="result" data-user="rashidnaushad" data-preview="true" class="codepen">See the Pen <a href="http://codepen.io/rashidnaushad/pen/pyPjae/">Tribute to Raghuram Rajan</a> by Rashid Naushad (<a href="http://codepen.io/rashidnaushad">@rashidnaushad</a>) on <a href="http://codepen.io">CodePen</a>.</p>
        <script async src="//assets.codepen.io/assets/embed/ei.js"></script>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="img img-responsive img-rounded" src="http://cleantallahassee.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/coming-soon.jpg" alt="Coming Soon!" />
        <div class="caption">
          <h5 class="text-center">Coming Soon!</h5>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="img img-responsive img-rounded" src="http://cleantallahassee.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/coming-soon.jpg" alt="Coming Soon!" />
        <div class="caption">
          <h5 class="text-center">Coming Soon!</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>-->
  </div>

  <div id="page3">
    <a id="contact"></a>
    <h3 id="contact-text" class="text-center">Think I can be of any help to you?<br>Wanna collaborate?<br>Shoot me a message, now!</h3>
    <a href="https://github.com/rashidnaushad" class="btn btn-lg col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2" target="_blank">GitHub</a>
    <div class="hidden-lg hidden-md">
      <br>
    </div>
    <a href="https://www.freecodecamp.com/rashidnaushad" class="btn btn-lg col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2" target="_blank">freeCodeCamp</a>
    <div class="hidden-lg hidden-md">
      <br>
    </div>
    <a href="mailto:rashidnaushad3@gmail.com" class="btn btn-lg col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-1 col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2" target="_blank">Gmail</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: worked like a charm..but what does `.btn ~ .btn` do?never came across this earlier?and do I now remove this 
`<div class="hidden-lg hidden-md">
      <br>
    </div> ` ?

Comment: The `~` is called sibling selector and target, in this case, all `.btn` that follows a `.btn`, which means the first `.btn` won't get `margin-top` as it doesn't need one. I also updated my answer with a media query so this happens only on smaller screens.